# If $a \mid c$ and $b \mid c$, but $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, then $ab \mid c$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, prime-factorization, gcd-and-lcm

> If $a | c$ and $b | c$ and $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime prove that
>   $ab|c$.

What I did was since $(a,b)=1$ then we can find integers $m,n$ such that $ma + nb=1$. Now since $a|c$ then $a = mc$. Similary, since $b|c$ then $b=nc$. Then I got that:

$$ma+nb=1$$
$$c(m+n)=1$$
$$m +n = 1/c$$
$$abm +abn=\frac{ab}{c}.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Oops: $a|c$ implies $c=ma$, not $a=mc$.

Comment: No it's not correct, because nothing tells you that the $m,n$ from $(a,b)=1$ are the same that the witnesses of $a|c$ and $b|c$. Try to use decomposition in prime factors instead.

Comment: Note that you have not proved that the $am+bn=1$ are the same values such that $c=am$.

Answer (score 2):

The key ideas are present in your proof.

We know that $a \mid c$ and $b \mid c$. As $a \mid c$, we have that $c = ak$ for some integer $k$. In this form, we see that $b \mid c = ak$, but $\gcd(a,b) = 1$. By the theorem below, we have that $b \mid k$, so that $k = b \ell$. Now $c = ak = ab\ell$, and now it's clear that $ab \mid c$.

> **Theorem**
>
> If $a \mid bc$ and $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, then $a \mid c$.

This can be proved from your application of Bezout's Theorem in your attempted solution. And in fact this is the content of [this question and its answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/417479/9754).

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).  We know $$c \equiv 0 \pmod a$$ and $$c \equiv 0 \pmod b$$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$.  Hence the Chinese Remainder Theorem implies $$c \equiv 0 \pmod {ab}.$$

This is the relevant line from the Wikipedia link:

> Hence $x \equiv y \pmod {n_i}$ for all $1 \leq i \leq k$, if and only if $x \equiv y \pmod N$.

Where $\{n_i\}_{i=1}^k$ are a set of coprime positive integers and $N=\prod_{i=1}^k n_i$.

Comment: I haven't seen mod yet. I should go study those first.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid prime factorization, try saying $c = kab + r$ with $0 \leq r < ab$. Then, because $a | c$ and $b|c$, we have that $a | r$ and $b | r$. Since $(a,b) = 1$, what can you say about $r$?