# Euclid's first theorem/ Euclid's lemma

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How to prove that if $c$ divides $ab$ and $\operatorname{gcd}(a,c)=1$, then show that $c$ divides $b$.

that means if $c|ab$ and $(a,c)=1 \implies c|b$.

Comment: Presumably you mean $(a,c) = 1$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $\gcd(a,b)= 1$ and $a$ divides $bc$ then $a$ divides $c\ $ \[Euclid's Lemma\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417479/if-gcda-b-1-and-a-divides-bc-then-a-divides-c-euclids-lemma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**.  If $\gcd(a,c)=1$ then there exist integers $x,y$ such that
$$ax+cy=1\ .$$
Now multiply both sides by $b$ and explain why $c$ is a factor of the left hand side.