# Let $a$ and $b$ be non-zero integers, and $c$ be an integer. Let $d = \gcd(a, b)$. Prove that if $a|c$ and $b|c$ then $ab|cd$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Let $a$ and $b$ be non-zero integers, and $c$ be an integer. Let $d = hcf(a, b)$. Prove that if $a|c$ and $b|c$ then $ab|cd$.

We know that if $a|c$ and $b|c$ then $a\cdot b\cdot s=c$ (for some positive integer $s$). $(ab|c)$

Then doesn't $ab|dc$ since $ab|c$?

I feel like I'm misunderstanding my givens.

Can we say $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=c$,  $\operatorname{hcf}(a,b)=d$, and $\operatorname{lcd}(a,b) \operatorname{hcf}(a*b)=a*b$?
Thus, $ab|dc$  as $dc = ab$.

Comment: $4|12$ and $6|12$ but there is no integer $s$ such that $24s | 12$.

Comment: Your second statement is wrong, as Tyler has pointed out. However, the assertion holds true when ${\rm gcd}(a,b)=1.$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\,\ a,b\mid c\,\Rightarrow\, ab\mid ca,cb\,\Rightarrow\, ab\mid (ca,cb) = c(a,b)\, $ by the GCD Distributive Law  (below).

---

Below are four proofs of the **GCD Distributive Law** $\rm\:(ax,bx) = (a,b)x\:$  using various approaches: Bezout's identity,  the universal gcd property, unique factorization, and induction.

---

First we show that the gcd distributive law follows immediately from the fact that, by Bezout, the [gcd may be specified by linear equations.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112026/242) Distributivity follows because such linear equations are preserved by scalings. Namely, for naturals $\rm\:a,b,c,x \ne 0$

$\rm\qquad\qquad \phantom{ \iff }\ \ \ \:\! c = (a,b) $

$\rm\qquad\qquad \iff\ \: c\:\ |\ \:a,\:b\ \ \ \  \ \ \&\ \ \ \ c\ =\ na\: +\: kb,\ \  \ $ some $\rm\:n,k\in \mathbb Z$

$\rm\qquad\qquad \iff\  cx\ |\ ax,bx\ \ \ \&\ \ \ cx = nax + kbx,\ \,$ some $\rm\:n,k\in \mathbb Z$

$\rm\qquad\qquad { \iff }\ \   cx = (ax,bx) $

The reader familiar with ideals will note that these equivalences are captured more concisely in the distributive law for ideal multiplication $\rm\:(a,b)(x) = (ax,bx),\:$ when interpreted in a PID or Bezout domain, where the ideal $\rm\:(a,b) = (c)\iff c = gcd(a,b)$

---

Alternatively, more generally, in *any* integral domain $\rm\:D\:$ we have

**Theorem** $\rm\ \ (a,b)\ =\ (ax,bx)/x\ \ $ if $\rm\ (ax,bx)\ $ exists in $\rm\:D.$

**Proof** $\rm\quad\: c\ |\ a,b \iff cx\ |\ ax,bx \iff cx\ |\ (ax,bx) \iff c\ |\ (ax,bx)/x\ \ \ $ **QED**

The above proof uses the [*universal* definitions of GCD, LCM](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/if-a-m-and-a-1-m-prove-aa-1-m/3149#3149), which often served to simplify proofs, e.g. see [this proof of the GCD * LCM law.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768/upper-and-lower-bounds-of-emptyset/3832#3832)

---

Alternatively, comparing powers of primes in unique  factorizations, it reduces to the following
$$\begin{eqnarray} \min(a+x,\,b+x) &\,=\,& \min(a,b) + x\\
\rm expt\ analog\ of\ \ \ \gcd(a \,* x,\,b \,* x)&=&\rm \gcd(a,b)\,*x\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad\ \ $$

The proof is *precisely* the same as the prior proof, replacing gcd by min, and divides by $\,\le,\,$ and using the universal property of min instead of that of gcd, i.e.

$$\begin{eqnarray} {\rm employing}\quad\ c\le a,b&\iff& c\le \min(a,b)\\
\rm the\ analog\ of\quad\   c\  \, |\, \ a,b&\iff&\rm c\ \,|\,\ \gcd(a,b) \end{eqnarray}$$

Then the above proof translates as below, $\ $ with $\,\ m(x,y) := {\rm min}(x,y)$

$c \le a,b \!\iff\!c\!+\!x \le a\!+\!x,b\!+\!x\!$ $\!\iff\! c\!+\!x \le m(a\!+\!x,b\!+\!x)\!$ $\!\iff\!\! c \le m(a\!+\!x,b\!+\!x)\!-\!x$

---

**Theorem** $\ \ $ If $\ a,b,x\ $ are positive naturals then $\ (ax,bx) = (a,b)x $

**Proof** $\ $ By induction on $\color{#0a0}{{\rm size}:= a\!+b}.\,$ If $\,a=b,\,$ $\,(ax,bx) = (ax,ax) = (a)x = (a,b)x\,$ hence it is true. $ $ Else $\,a\neq b;\,$ wlog, by symmetry, $\,a > b\,$ so $\,(ax,bx) = (ax\!-\!bx,bx) = \color{}{((a\!-\!b)x,bx)}\,$ with smaller $\rm\color{#0a0}{size}$ $\,(a\!-\!b) + b = a < \color{#0a0}{a\!+b},\,$ therefore $\,((a\!-\!b)x,bx)\!\underset{\rm induct}=\! (a\!-\!b,b)x = (a,b)x$.

---

For completeness below we present a proof of the **LCM Distributive Law** with notation $\,[x,y] := {\rm lcm}(x,y),\,$  using the [LCM universal property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2322544/242) and basic divisibility properties.

**Theorem** $\ \ [ax,bx] = [a,b]x $

**Proof** $\ \ [ax,bx]\mid c\iff ax,bx\mid c\iff a,b\mid c/x\iff [a,b]\mid c/x\iff [a,b]x\mid c$

Therefore $\ [ax,bx] = [a,b]x\,$ since they divide each other by above.

Comment: what do you mean by $(ax,bx)/x$ ? Do you mean inverse of $x$ ?

Comment: @SaunDev $\ (m,n)\,$ means $\,\gcd(m,n).\,$ This notation is widely used in number theory.

Comment: Dubuque : yes I perfectly understand that ... what I mean to say is what do you mean by that $1/x$  ? [ $x$ is not necessarily unit ... ]

Comment: @SaunDev $\ x\mid ax,bx\,\Rightarrow\, x\mid (ax,bx),\,$ so it denotes the quotient.

Comment: Dubuque : ah yes ... I see , thank you

Comment: Hi, in your second proof how the fact that D is an integral domain useful?? Sorry if it's trivial.

Comment: @HodaBibo e.g. it uses: $x\neq 0\Rightarrow\, x\,$ cancellable (i.e.$\,xy = xz\Rightarrow y = z)\,$ in order to cancel $x$ in the divisibilties.

Answer (score 0):

As an extreme example, let $a=b=c=4$. Then $a$ divides $c$ and $b$ divides $c$, but $ab$ does not divide $c$.  So the approach you suggested will need modification.

Now let us prove the stated result.  Because $d$ is the highest common factor of $a$ and $b$, there exist integers $s$ and $t$ such that
$as+bt=d$. (This is often called Bézout's lemma.) It follows that
$$cas+cbt=cd.$$
Because $b$ divides $c$, we have $ab$ divides $cas$. Because $a$ divides $c$, we have $ab$ divides $cbt$. So $ab$ divides $cas+cbt$, that is, $ab$ divides $cd$.

Comment: Remark that the above proof essentially employs the *gcd distributive law* (see the first Bezout-based  proof in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Let us put it this way: Define a', b' so that a=a'd and b=b'd, where d=GCD(a,b).  Then a|c means c = a'ds for some s, and b|c means c = b'dt for some t.  But that doesn't mean ab|c because we could have a'|t and b'|s, i.e c = a'b'du for some u.  I.e in dividing c, a and b are *sharing d* between them.

Of course, if c = a'b'du, cd = a'db'du = abu.