# Let $R$ a ring with maximum common divisor. If $a,b,c \in R$ such that $a|bc$ and $(a,b)=1$ then $a|c$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ a ring with maximum common divisor. Show that if $a,b,c \in R$ such that $a|bc$ and $(a,b)=1$ then $a|c$.

**Comments:** I tried to use the Bezout's theorem, but in my course we saw it only applies to principal domains, I tried to use the setting as well, but could not finish.

Comment: The term "maximum common divisor" has a couple different denotations. Which is yours?

Comment: If $(a,b)=1$, I always worth the Bezout's theorem, R is not even PID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ You can generalize the Bezout-based proof by replacing the Bezout linear combination $\,\color{#c00}{ja+kb = 1}\,$ by the gcd $\,\color{#0a0}{(a,b)=1}.\,$ Then the use of the integer distributive law is replaced by the use of the  [GCD Distributive Law,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/785544/242) namely

$\qquad\qquad a\mid bc\,\Rightarrow\,a\mid ac,bc\,\Rightarrow\, a\mid jac\!+\!kbc = (\color{#c00}{ja+kb})c = c$

$\qquad\qquad a\mid bc\,\Rightarrow\, a\mid ac,bc\,\Rightarrow\, a\mid\, (ac,\ bc)\ =\ \color{#0a0}{(a,\ b)}\,c = c$

Comment: @Groos I added the Bezout proof to show the analogy. Note that you may need to *prove* the gcd distributive law (and possibly some other minor points) depending on what you already know. The above is just a *sketch* of the main ideas.