# If $c\mid ab$ and $\gcd(c,a)=d$, then $c\mid db$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I came across this problem in my number theory text and am having a bit of trouble with it:

Prove if $c\mid ab$ and $\gcd(c,a)=d$, then $c\mid db$.

Here's what I have so far:

If $c\mid ab$, then there exists an integer $x$ such that $cx=ab$.
Because $\gcd(c,a)=d$, $d\mid c$ and $d\mid a$. Let $y$ be such that $dy=a$. 
Then,
$$cx=ab=dyb,$$
so $$cx \frac{d}{a} = db.$$
But I don't know how to show that $\frac{dx}{a}$ is an integer. Can anyone please offer ideas on what I've done so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Bézout's identity. Since $\gcd(c, a) = d$, we know that there exist $s,t \in \mathbb Z$ such that:
$$
cs + at = d \iff bcs + abt = bd
$$
Since $ c \mid ab$, we know that there exists some $x \in \mathbb Z$ such that $cx = ab$, so:
$$
bd = bcs + (cx)t = c(\underbrace{bs + xt}_{\in ~ \mathbb Z})
$$
Hence, $c \mid bd$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ c\mid cb,ab\,\Rightarrow\,c\mid (cb,ab)\overset{\rm\color{#c00}{ DL}}= (c,a)b = db\ \ $ **QED**

Above we used the *gcd Distributive Law* ($\rm\color{#c00}{DL}$). Three proofs of DL [are here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/785544/242)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Bezout's theorem: There exists $x, y$ integers s.t. $cx + ay = d$. Then, multiplying by $b$ helds

$$c b x + a b y = b d$$

But $c \mid ab$, hence $c\mid bd$

Answer (score 0):

There are no mistakes in what you've done so far, but I agree that it's not immediately apparent why $dx/a$ is an integer.

I would start by noting that the answer to this problem is well known when $d = 1$, so maybe I should try to turn it into a problem about relatively prime integers. So write $a = da'$ and $c = dc'$, and consider what the gcd of $a'$ and $c'$ is. Then see if you can carry on from there by reformulating the problem using $a'$ and $c'$ rather than $a$ and $c$.

Just a note: It *is* possible to do this problem without appealing to Bezout's Theorem. In other words, for those familiar with rings, the fact is valid in factorial rings, not just principal ones.