# Use of GCD Distributive Law in proof of Euclid's Lemma

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Suppose that c|ab and (b, c) = 1. Then c|a

Proof
(ab, ac) =|a|(b, c) = |a|. But by hypothesis, one has c|ab, which implies that c|(ab, ac).
We thus conclude that c|a. And the proof is complete.

I am sure it is very simple but I cant seem to understand the stage c|ab implies that c|(ab,ac). I would appreciate if someone could show me this.

Comment: because clearly $c$ divides $ac$. And if $x$ is a divisor of $y$ and $z$ it divides their GCD.

Answer (score 3):

Since $(b,c)=1$ there exist integers $k,l$ with $kb+lc=1$. Now $c\mid ab$ implies $c$ divides $kab=a(1-lc)=a-alc$. Since $c\mid alc$ it follows that $c\mid a$.

Comment: Better to invoke the gcd distributive law by name rather than *reprove* it every time you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Greatest common divisior of $x$ and $y$ is a number with a property that $d \mid x$ and $d \mid y$ implies $d \mid \gcd(x,y)$.

In your case we have $c \mid ab$ from assumption and $c \mid ac$ trivially, because $\frac{ac}{c}=a$. Hence, $c \mid \gcd(ab,ac)$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 0):

It uses basic gcd laws. By the [GCD Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/785544/242) $\,\rm\color{#c00}{DL}\, $ we have

$\qquad\ c\mid ab\iff c\mid ab,ac \color{#0a0}\iff c\mid (ab,ac)\overset{\color{#c00}{\rm D\:\!L}} = a(b,c) \iff c/(b,c)\mid a$

Above we employed $\,\ c\mid j,k\color{#0a0}\iff c\mid (j,k),\,$ the [GCD Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3356212/242).