# Constant in GCD

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $gcd(a,b) = 1$ then is it true that $gcd(2a,2b) = 2$? More generally, if $gcd(a,b) = k$ then is it true that $gcd(an,bn) = n*gcd(a,b) = kn$?

Looking at Bézout's identity this seems to be the case since we could simply multiply both sides of the equation $ax + by = d$ by the constant $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is  special case of the **gcd distributive law** $\ \gcd(na,nb)\, =\, n\gcd(a,b).\ $

[See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785465/let-a-and-b-be-non-zero-integers-and-c-be-an-integer-let-d-hcfa-b/785544#785544) for a few proofs of this law (by Bezout, universal property, and prime factorizations).

Answer (score 1):

Let $n\ne 0$, and let $k=\gcd(a,b)$. It is not hard to see that $nk$ divides each of $na$ and $nb$.

Now we need to show that every common divisor of $na$ and $nb$ divides $nk$. Here we use the Bezout "Identity." There exist integers $s$ and $t$ such that $sa+tb=k$. Multiply through by $n$. We get $s(na)+t(nb)=nk$. From this we can see that any common divisor of $na$ and $nb$ divides $nk$.

**Remark:** The harder  part of the argument was already in the OP.

Comment: This is the Bezout method I mention. In the link I highlight how it arises from the *preservation* under scalings of objects defined by *linear* equations and divisibility relations, i.e. by innate scaling symmetry.

Comment: The link, and your earlier posts along similar lines, are very useful.