# GCD proof? $(a,bc) = (a,b)(a,c)$ if $(b,c)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This seems like it should be an easy problem, but I just can't seem to get anywhere.

What I've tried:

- trying to show that $(a,bc)$ and $(a,b)(a,c)$ divide each other by writing out equations (like $a=dk$ for $d= (a,bc)$)
- trying to expand using Bezout's Identity

Comment: It's true more generally if $\ (a,b,c)=1,\ $ see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

$(a,b)(a,c) = ((a,b)a,(a,b)c) = (a^2,ab,ac,bc) = (a(a,\color{#c00}{b,c}),bc) = (a,bc)\,$ by $\,\color{#c00}{(b,c)}=1$

Comment: Can you explain the first equality?

Comment: It's the gcd distributive law $\ d(a,c) = (da,dc)\,$ then applied again in the second equality, etc. [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/785544/242) for a handful of proofs of the fundamental GCD distributive law.