# Prove that $a$ divides $bc$ involving $\gcd$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that $a|bc$ if and only if $\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}|c$.

For the $\Rightarrow$ direction we know that there is a $u$ so that $bc=ua$ and we need to show the existence of a $v$ so that $c=v\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}$. From what we know $c=\frac{ua}{b}$. Choosing $v=\frac{u \gcd(a,b)}{b}$ leads to the desired result. A similar argument can be made for the opposite direction.

Is this correct? Because it seems too simple for me as it doesn't involve properties of the $\gcd$ at all.

Comment: You can easily compare your proof with the ones from a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941259/a-divides-bc-if-and-only-if). Then you can replace your vague statement "A similar argument leads to..." by a valid proof. "Is this correct?" This depends on the grading scheme. It is certainly not yet full points.

Comment: you need to make sure each of these numbers is a positive integer.

Comment: ... in particular $v$

Comment: Use `$x\mid y$` for $x\mid y$.