# How can I show that in a UFD $\operatorname{gcd} (ra,rb) \sim r \operatorname{gcd} (a,b)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

> Let $R$ be a UFD. Let $r,a,b \in R$. Then how can I show that $\operatorname{gcd} (ra,rb) \sim r \operatorname{gcd} (a,b)$?

If $\operatorname{gcd} (a,b) = d$ and $\operatorname{gcd} (ra,rb) = d'$.Then $d|a$ and $d|b$ $\implies$ $rd|ra$ and $rd|rb$ i.e. $rd$ becomes a common divisor of $ra$ and $rb$. Hence we must have $rd|d'$. But I fail to show the converse part i.e. $d'|rd$.

How can I show this? Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See the 2nd and 3rd [proofs here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/785544/242) of this **GCD Distributive Law**.

Comment: $d=ax+by \Rightarrow rd=rax+rby=(ra)x+(rb)y$ then $d'|(ra)x+(rb)y\Rightarrow d'|rd$

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay. You are right. That only works if $R$ is a bezout domain.

Comment: No.As far as I know this thing is true in PID and hence in ED.But how can you prove it in a UFD?Please tell me.

Comment: I said it to Mustafa not you @mathchat.

Comment: @MathChat Correct, UFDs need not be Bezour domains, e.g. in $\,R = \Bbb Z[x,y]\,$ we have $\,\gcd(x,y)=1\,$ but there are no $\,f,g\in R\,$ with $\,x f + y g = 1\,$ (else eval at $\,x=0=y\,$ yields $0 = 1).\,$  That's why I  mentioned only the proofs that do not use Bezout / Euclid in my linked answer.

Comment: @ Bill Dubuque. Yes. You are absolutely right.

Comment: I did notice you used $\sim$ rather than $=$, but I still feel a bit uneasy about the possibility, for example, that $r$ is negative while $a$ and $b$ are positive.