# Showing that ord(a,b)*gcd(a,b,n)=n

Tags: number-theory

$ord(a,b)$ is the order of the element (a,b) in the additive group $(\mathbb{Z}/(n))^2$.

Why is $ord(a,b)\cdot gcd(a,b,n)=n$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The order of $(a,b)$ in $(\mathbb Z_n)^2$ is the smallest $k$ such that
$$
k(a,b)=(0,0)\in(\mathbb Z_n)^2\iff ka=kb=0\in\mathbb Z_n
$$
Now let $k$ be any integer satisfying the above relation. Then using Bezout's identity
$$
\gcd(a,b)=\lambda a+\gamma b
$$
and considering it modulo $n$ we get
$$
k\cdot\gcd(a,b)=\lambda ka+\gamma kb=\lambda 0+\gamma 0\in\mathbb Z_n
$$
In particular this works for $k=\operatorname{ord}(a,b)$ which is just a particular such value of $k$.

Comment: Thank you @String but why ist $ord(a,b)\cdot gcd(a,b,n)=\lambda ka+\gamma kb+\alpha kn=n?$ and not a multiple of $n$?

Answer (score 0):

The order of $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ is given by: $LCM\left(\frac{n}{(a,n)}, \frac{n}{(b,n)}\right)$. Now we have:

$$\left[\frac{n}{(a,n)}, \frac{n}{(b,n)}\right] = \frac{n^2}{(b,n)(a,n)\left(\frac{n}{(a,n)}, \frac{n}{(b,n)}\right)} = \frac{n^2}{(b,n)(a,n)\frac{n}{[(a,n),(b,n)]}} = \frac{n(a,n)(b,n)}{(b,n)(a,n)((a,n),(b,n))} = \frac{n}{(a,b,n)}$$

Where we used the notation $(a,b) = GCD(a,b)$ and $[a,b] = LCM(a,b)$

Answer (score 0):

$n\mid ka,kb \iff n\mid ka,kb,kn\!\! \overset{\ \ \rm\color{#c00}{U}}\iff n\mid (ka,kb,kn)\overset{\rm\color{#0a0}{D}}=(a,b,n)k\iff n/(a,b,n)\mid k$

${\rm ord}(a,b)\, $ is the *least* positive such $k,\,$ which, by above, is clearly $\,k = n/(a,b,n).$

Above we used $\:\rm\color{#c00}{U} = $ gcd [Universal property:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189430/242) $\,\ n\mid i,j\iff n\mid(i,j)$

Also, $ $ we used  $\, $ $\rm\color{#0a0}{D}$ = gcd [Distributive law:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/785544/242) $\,\ (ik,jk,\ell k) = (i,j,\ell)k$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: But your proof works also for $ord(a,b)=n/(a,b)$ or am I wrong?

Comment: @Mandarine Wrong, because in the final arrow we require $\,(a,b,n)\mid n\,$ when we cancel $\,(a,b,n)\,$ from the divisibility relation. But that won't work for $\,(a,b)\,$ since generally $\,(a,b)\nmid n\ \ $

Comment: Yes you are right, I didn't see that. Thank you @ Bill Dubuque.