# If $(b,c) = 1$, then $(a,bc) = (a,b)(a,c)$

Tags: number-theory

I do not know how to solve the following:

> Show that If $(b,c) = 1$, then $(a,bc) = (a,b)(a,c)$

Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Tell us what did you try!

Answer (score 2):

Distributing: $\ (a,b)(a,c) = ((a,b)a,(a,b)c) = (aa,ab,ac,bc) = (a\!\!\!\!\!\overbrace{(a,\color{#c00}{b,c})}^{\large =1\ {\rm by}\  \color{#c00}{(b,c)=1}}\!\!\!\!\!,bc) = (a,bc)$

**Remark** $ $ We used only the [GCD Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/785544/242) $\ x(y,z) = (xy,xz)\ $ and other universal gcd laws (associative, commutative) therefore the result holds true in *any* gcd domain (vs. proofs using Bezout or primes, which are not as general).

Comment: Notice that the proof requires only the weaker hypothesis that $\ (a,b,c) = 1\ $

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Assume that $p$ is a prime number and that $p|a$ and $p|bc.$ That is $p|a$ and $p|b$ or $p|c.$ So $p|\gcd(a,b)$ or $p|\gcd(a,c).$ In any case $$p|\gcd(a,b)\gcd(a,c).$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: I don't think that division by primes is enough of a proof. Shouldn't you divide by $p^n$ for some $n$?

Comment: @Jakobian It is only a hint and not a complete answer.