# Prove that $a \mid bc$ implies $a \mid \gcd(a,b)\times \gcd(a,c)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I want to show that $a \mid bc$ implies $a \mid \gcd(a,b)\times \gcd(a,c)$.

My answer: since
$$ a\mid ac \quad \text{ and } \quad a\mid bc,$$
we get that $a \mid \gcd(ac,bc)$ which implies that
$$ a \mid |c|\gcd(a,b).$$

However, I don't know the final step.

Comment: Do you mean "gcd" which is "greatest common divisor" instead of "gdc"? Or am I just ignorant?

Comment: Equivalently (at least, in $\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$), is it true that $x\le y+z$ implies $x\le \min(x,y)+\min(x,z)$ ? The answer is yes.

Comment: @Accelerator Yes GCD, modifications has been made

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove if $n\mid ab$, then $n\mid [\gcd(a,n) \times \gcd(b,n)]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2983344/prove-if-n-mid-ab-then-n-mid-gcda-n-times-gcdb-n) - found in the RHS "Related" section list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the $gcd$ is a linear combination. i.e. $(a,b)(a,c)$ can be written as

$$(a,b)(a,c)=(am+bn)(ak+cl)=a^2mk+amcl+bnak+bncl$$

$$=a(amk+mcl+bnk) + bc(nl)$$

If $a\mid bc$ then $a$ divides the right hand side.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque It was original to me. I did not search, but I will strive to do so.