# How to prove the following statement: $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ and $a=bc$ implies $a\mid c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

If $a$ and $b$ are coprime, i.e. $\gcd(a,b) = 1 = ax+by$, for certain integer $x$ and $y$, and $a = bc$, then $a \mid c$

I've tried multiply $c$ to both sides of $1 = ax+by$, but didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that this strategy didn't work out?

Comment: In fact with these conditions  $b=\pm 1$, otherwise $bc$ has prime factors not in $a$.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/417479) and other posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/417479).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [suppose $\gcd(a,b)= 1$ and $a$ divides $bc$. Show that $a$ must divide $c$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417479/suppose-gcda-b-1-and-a-divides-bc-show-that-a-must-divide-c)

Comment: $1 = ax + by = bcx + by = b(cx + y)$ so $b|1$ so $b = \pm 1$ so $a = \pm c$.  So $\gcd (a,b)=\gcd(bc,b)=1$ so $b|1$ so $b = \pm 1$ so $a =\pm c$.

Answer (score 1):

As $a=bc$, $a|bc$.

From Bezout's identity, there exist $x,y$ such that
$xa+yb=1$.
Multiply both sides by $c$ and get
$$xac+ybc=c.$$
$xac$ is divisible by $a$, $ybc$ is divisible by $bc$, which is divisible (by hypothesis) by $a$. So $c$ must also be divisble by $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Still it should work if you use all the hypotheses: you obtain $c=acx+bcy$. Now, $a$ is supposed to divide $bc$, i.e. there exists $k\in \mathbf Z$ such that $bc=ak$, so
$$c=acx+aky=a(cx+ky).$$

Comment: how can we make sure cx+ky is integer？

Comment: ??? All numbers are integers in this situation!