# Find $f \in \mathbb{Q}(X)$ so that the ideal $(2,X)f = (2f,Xf) \subset \mathbb{Z}[X]$

Tags: ring-theory, gcd-and-lcm

In the title $(2, X)$ is the ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ generated by $2$ and $X$.
I'm reading that the answer should be $f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ because $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is a $UFD$ and $2$ and $X$ are relatively prime. Can anyone elaborate? I understand that $2$ and $X$ are relatively prime and $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is an $UFD$. Of course, I would also be interested in a direct proof.
Possible answer: Let $f=\dfrac {p}{q}$, with $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ without common prime factors. $f(2,X) \subset \mathbb{Z}[X]$ if and only if $2f$ and $Xf$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. First condition gives: $2p=z_1q$ so $2 | z_1$ or $2|q$. If $2|z_1$ then $q | p$, impossible (unless $q=1$), so $2 | q$. In a similar way, $X | q$, so $f= \dfrac{p}{2Xq'}$, but then $2f \notin \mathbb{Z}[X]$ since $X$ does not divide $p$.

Comment: What do you mean by the notation $f.(2,X)$?

Comment: Just the product, so $ \left \{ f(2z_1+Xz_2)  | z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{Z}[X] \right \} $

Comment: OK. Certainly if $f$ has integer coefficients then all elements of $f.(2,X)$ have integer coefficients. And if $f$ doesn't have integer coefficients, then neither does $Xf(X)$.

Comment: Actually, I'm very sorry to have wasted your time, I messed up. Had to be $\mathbb{Q}(X)$ and not $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ in the title. I've edited and attemped an answer.

Comment: I added some *conceptual* remarks to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ If $\,g,h\,$ are denominators for a fraction $f\,$ then so too is their gcd $\,(g,h).\,$ So in particular (OP), a fraction writable with $\rm\color{#c00}{coprime}$ denominators  is "integral" (writable with denominator $\color{#c00}1$).

**Theorem** $ $ If $\,g,h\in \Bbb Z[x],\ f \in \Bbb Q[x]\,$ then $\,gf,hf\in\Bbb Z[x]\,\Rightarrow\, (g,h)f\in \Bbb Z[x].$

**Proof** $\ $  Write $f = p/q,\ p,q\in \Bbb Z[x].\,$  Then  $\, gf,hf =  gp/q, hp/q\in \Bbb Z[x]\,$ hence

$$q\mid gp,hp\,\overset{\rm\color{#90f}U}\Rightarrow\, q\mid (gp,hp) \overset{\color{#0a0}{\rm D}}= \color{c00}{(g,h)}p\ \ {\rm so}\ \ (g,h)f \in \Bbb Z[x]\qquad $$

where we used $\,\color{#0a0}{\rm D} = $ [GCD Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242), valid in every GCD doamin (e.g. here the UFD $\,\Bbb Z[x])$, $ $ and we also used: $ $  $\rm\color{#90f}U = $ [GCD Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189430/242).

**Remark** $ $ This property of denominators often proves (conceptually) handy, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1165413/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3295370/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1197025/242). See also [various posts one *denominator and order ideals*.](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+%28dubuque+OR+%22math+gems%22+OR+%22key+ideas%22%29+%28%22denominator+ideal%22+OR+%22order+ideal%22%29)