# Who first proved that a fraction writable with coprime denominators is an integer?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, math-history

> Let $a$ and $b$ be two coprime integers and $q \in \mathbb{Q}^*$. If $qa,\ qb \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $q \in \mathbb{Z}.$

From which historical mathematician does this lemma come? Any references?

Comment: Euclid?${{{}}}$

Comment: Denominators for $q$ are closed under subtraction so also under gcd, thus if $\,a,b\,$ are deominators for $q$ so too is $\,\gcd(a,b) = 1,\,$ i,e, $\,q\in\Bbb Z.\,$ Proofs like this became obvious once ideals were known. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1197025/242) for further discussion of such denominator (and order) ideals. It is probably difficult to date the first time this *precise* statement is known (before ideal theory).

Comment: Not all lemma's are historically traceible.  I've never heard of this lemma but it fairly clear and easy to prove.  I doubt there is any history to it.  Euclid may or may not have proven it.

Comment: @Maman FYI, in case you didn't know about it, you may wish to consider in the future if these types of questions may be better suited for the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: fyi: it's [easy to show](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3295370/242) that this is equivalent to Euclid's Lemma and closely related results. @fleablood Surprised to hear that you've never seen it since I explicitly highlight it frequently here when discussing denominator (and order) ideals (e.g. the link in my prior comment) Maybe I should use brighter colors!

Comment: Well... I never heard of this *lemma* as stated as a specific result worth remembering and referring. If I ever needed the results I'd figure they'd be easy to derive or even to just dismiss as "a clear immediate corollary to Euclid's Lemma".  There's lots of lemmas I never heard of.  I've never heard of the Lemma that all positive integers may be written as $3^k*M$ where $M$ is an integer not divisible by $3$ and I dare say you've never heard it either (odd that I can quote it despite never having heard it....)

Comment: @fleablood Not only have I heard it, but I've also proved it here at least a handful of times (e.g. the analog for the prime $2$ when discussing proofs of irrationality of $\sqrt 2$).

Comment: @Gone Thanks for your suggestion !

Comment: Special case $(a,b)= 1$ of the [Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1165413/242) in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 0):

Setting $q=r/s$, this is equivalent to: if $(a,b)=1$ and $s\mid ra$ and $s\mid rb$, then $s\mid r$.

I doubt there is a specific significant first appearance of this lemma, but indeed it could have been proved by Euclid: write $1=ax+by$ for integers $x,y$, and then
$$
r=1r=(ax+by)r = (ra)x+(rb)y
$$
is a multiple of $s$.

While this proof uses the "Bezout identity" $(a,b)=ax+by$, which was [apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#History) due to [Bachet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Gaspard_Bachet_de_M%C3%A9ziriac) in the early 17th century, the Euclidean algorithm leads naturally to that statement, and thus one could algorithmically compute $r/s$ and know from Euclidean principles that the answer will be an integer.

Comment: Almost everything in elementary divisibility theory is equivalent to results on gcds and lcms. But that doesn't mean they were all discovered at the same time. Many things that are easily seen  to be equivalent nowadays were very difficult to see in older times due to lack of modern theory.