# Euclid's Lemma for Euclidean Ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

Question: If $R$ is a euclidean ring and $\pi\in R$ is irreducible, prove that $\pi\mid\alpha\beta$ implies $\pi\mid\alpha$ or $\pi\mid\beta$.

A solution is to prove all euclidean rings are PIDs, then prove Euclid's Lemma is true in PIDs. However, is there a solution **need not to prove $R$ is a PID** and use the definition of euclidean ring directly? And the solution may not use $gcd$ because **the existence of $gcd$ doesn't confirm** without PID's help.

Forgive my poor English.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252746/can-the-euclidean-algorithm-prove-euclids-lemma-in-a-ufd?rq=1.

Comment: I beg to differ. the existence of a gcd need not go through proving that $R$ is a PID. You need only apply Euclid's algorithm in a clever way.

Comment: @Andreas Caranti Thanks,I got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ If not $\exists$ irred $\,p\!:\ pc = ab,\ p\nmid a,b.\,$ From such counterexamples with min $\,|p|\,$ choose one with min $\,|a|.\,$ Then $\,|a| < |p|,\ $ else $\,a\mapsto \bar a\, =\, a\ {\rm mod}\ p\, =\, a - rp\ne 0\,$ is a counterexample with $\,|\bar a| < |a|.\,$ Now $\,p\nmid b\,\Rightarrow\,a\,$ is a nonunit, so it has an irred factor $\,q\mid a.$ By  $\,|p|\,$ minimal and $\,|q|<|p|$ we infer $\,q\mid  pc,\ q\nmid p\,\Rightarrow\, q\mid c,\ $ so $\ p(c/q) = (a/q)b\,$ is a counterexample with $\,|a/q| < |a|$ contra hypothesis.

Comment: I clicked this answer on the front page by curiosity, and it did not take more than 30 seconds to realize that the answer is written in a cryptic shorthand rather than standard mathematical English.

Comment: @CarlMummert So you downvoted because because I used $\,\exists\,$ instead of "there exists" and abbreviated irreducible? How nice of you. Don't you realize that doing so might mislead students into thinking that there might be something wrong with the answer?

Comment: I voted because I *do* think there is something wrong with the answer: I do not think it is useful in its present form. If a student submitted an answer such as this in an undergraduate class, what grade would it receive? I fear this style of presentation might "mislead" students into thinking that this is how mathematics is usually written. Of course, I am certain the idea can be improved into a useful answer. But it is not there yet. I think that is a complete explanation of my reasoning.

Comment: @CarlMummert It is not meant to be an answer submitted by a *student*. Rather, it is meant to be a **hint** sketched by a *teacher*, not unlike a hint one might find in a textbook. In any case, if there is something you do not understand then please tell me *precisely* what that is and I will be happy to elaborate.