# If a prime divides a product then it must divide a factor of the product [Euclid's Lemma]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

We have $q, p$ prime and $tq = (p-1)(p+1)$ for some positive integer $t$. The book I'm reading says that because $q$ is prime, it divides $p-1$ or $p+1$.

**Question:** Why exactly does it matter that $q$ is prime here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic consequence of the *existence and uniqueness* of prime factorizations is **Euclid's Lemma:**  **if a prime $p$ divides a product then it must divide some factor.** Indeed if $\, pc = ab\,$ then appending the unique prime factorizations of $a$ and $b$ necessarily yields the unique prime factorization of $ab$. By uniqueness this is the same as the factorization of $pc$ obtained similarly, where $p$ occurs, so $p$ must also occur in the prime factorization of $a$ or $b$, i.e. $\,p\mid a\,$ or $\,p\mid b.\,$ Notice the crucial role played here by *uniqueness* (which actually occurs more times than I mentioned explicitly). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252748/242) for a proof using gcds, and further remarks.

Conversely if $p$ isn't prime then $\,p = ab,\ a,b>1$ so  $\,p\mid ab\,$ but $\,p\nmid a\, $ (else $\,p\!=\!ab\mid a\,\Rightarrow\,b\mid 1)\,$ and similarly $\,p\nmid b,\,$ so the above fundamental  "prime divisor property" fails for composites, hence Euclid's Lemma *characterizes* primes (among nonzero nonuinit integers). In fact Euclid's Lemma is used as [the definition of a prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2983648/242) in more general rings (where it is generally distinct from the property of being irreducible, i.e. having only trvial splittings where one factor is a unit).

Comment: This is correct but often the existence of prime factorization if proved by the Euclid's Lemma, and this may lead to circular thinking.

Comment: @AlessandroF Euclid is used to prove *uniqueness* not existence. There are many ways to do so  besides Euclid's Lemma, though most boil down to using the fact that $\Bbb Z$ is a Euclidean domain. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3057093/242) for many of these closely related properties.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $q=15$ and $t=8$.  This gives $p-1=10$ and $p+1=12$.  Here, since $q$ is composite, it is possible (and has happened!) that it divides neither $p-1$ nor $p+1$, because its factors can be split between the two.  This can't happen with prime $q$: it can't be split into non-trivial factors, so it must divide one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

If $tq$ $=$ $(p-1)(p+1)$, then $p$ $=$ $±1$ $\pmod q$ weather $p$ or $q$ are prime or not. (Since it is divisible by either factor $p-1$ or $p+1$.) Again, $(p-1)(p+1)$ is factorable into primes ([Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic)) therefore $q$ may be a prime dividing $p-1$ or $p+1$ in some cases, otherwise it is a product of primes dividing $p-1$ or $p+1$. Your requirement for $p$ being prime is unessessary-- everything I had explained will still be true weather $p$ is prime or not. Note: This is also of the factorization $p^2-1$ $=$ $(p-1)(p+1)$.