# In what kind of rings a divisor of a product is a product of divisors?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, soft-question, terminology, divisibility

In a [unique factorisation domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain#Examples), if $a|bc$, then $a$ can be written as $a = a_1a_2$ so that $a_1|b$ and $a_2|c$.

Is this property of a commutative ring strictly weaker than the property of being a UFD?  If so, does it have a name, or is it equivalent to some other well-known property?

Comment: I doubt this is equivalent to being a UFD, since I can't see how that would imply _existence_ of factorizations. However, this condition implies that every irreducible element is prime, so it implies uniqueness of factorizations, at least assuming the ring is a domain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such rings are known as *pre-Schreier* rings. The property easily yields that atoms (irreducibles) are prime, so it is equivalent to being a UFD in atomic domains (nonzero nonunits factor into atoms), but is weaker in absence of that. Below is a summary of related properties of *domains*.

PID:  $\ \ $  every ideal is principal

Bezout: $\ \ $ every ideal (a,b) is principal

GCD: $\ \ $   (x,y) := gcd(x,y) exists for all x,y

SCH:  $\ \ $  Schreier = pre-Schreier & integrally closed

SCH0: $\ \ $  pre-Schreier: a|bc  $\, \Rightarrow\, $  a = BC, B|b, C|c

D:  $\ \ $    (a,b) = 1  &  a|bc  $\,\Rightarrow\,$  a|c

PP:  $\ \ $   (a,b) = (a,c) = 1   $\,\Rightarrow\,$  (a,bc) = 1

GL:  $\ \ $   Gauss Lemma: product of primitive polys is primitive

GL2:  $\ \ $  Gauss Lemma holds for all polys of degree 1

AP: $\ \ $    atoms are prime [AP = PP restricted to atomic a]

[image]

Since  atomic & AP $\,\Rightarrow\,$ UFD, reversing the above  UFD $\,\Rightarrow\,$ AP  path shows that in atomic domains all these properties (except PID, Bezout) collapse, becoming all equivalent to UFD.

There are also many properties known equivalent to D, e.g.

[a] $\ \ $    (a,b) = 1  $\,\Rightarrow\,$     a|bc  $\,\Rightarrow\,$   a|c

[b] $\ \ $    (a,b) = 1  $\,\Rightarrow\,$    a,b|c  $\,\Rightarrow\,$  ab|c

[c] $\ \ $    (a,b) = 1  $\,\Rightarrow\,$  (a)/\(b) =  (ab)

[d] $\ \ $    (a,b) exists  $\,\Rightarrow\,$  lcm(a,b) exists

[e]  $\ \ $   a + b X  irreducible  $\,\Rightarrow\,$  prime  for b $\ne$ 0 (deg = 1)

You can find proofs of most of the above (including counterexamples for implication reversals) by looking up papers by D. Anderson and M. Zafrullah with the keywords "Schreier" and "Gauss's Lemma". See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/6657/242) for links on related topics such as the classical Euler four number theorem (Vierzahlensatz), Riesz interpolation, etc.

Comment: Actually, my original question was not only about domains.  I am also interested to know how this property relates to other usual properties when there are zero divisors.