# Divisors of a multiple of a prime (or any integer)

Tags: number-theory, integers

I have been studying group theory for some time now, and I have noted that quite a few theorems/proofs considering finite groups rely on results from number theory, a branch of mathematics of which I have very little knowledge.

One question that I would like to have answered concerns the divisors of a product of integers.

Let *m* and *n* be integers. Is it true (and can you prove/disprove) that the divisors of *mn* are either divisors of *m*, divisors of *n* or common multiples of *m* and *n*?

In particular, is it true that the divisors of *mp* with *p* a prime number are either multiples of *p* or divisors of *m*?

Comment: Notice that $6 \cdot 15 = 90$ has divisor $9$, which is neither divisor of $6$ or $15$, nor common multiple, nor common divisor of both.

Comment: By the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) every integer has a unique factorization into prime numbers

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) says if $p$ is prime and divides $ab$ then $p$ divides $a$ or $b$, but that may not be true if $p$ isn't prime

Comment: Your last conjecture is correct:  if $p$ is prime then any divisor of $mp$ is either a multiple of $p$ or a divisor of $m$.  This follows quickly from unique factorization.

Comment: [An Introductory Course in Elementary
Number Theory](https://resources.saylor.org/wwwresources/archived/site/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/An-Introductory-in-Elementary-Number-Theory.pdf) see chapter "2.3 The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic" for more information on what the previous comments already mentioned.

Comment: What *is* true is that [a divisor of a product is a product of divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1137305/242). This is equivalent to uniqueness of prime factorizations (and [many other equivalent notions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3057093/242))