# $x \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and $x \equiv 1 \pmod q \Rightarrow x \equiv 1 \pmod {pq}$ proven in a certain way

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Let $p$ and $q$ be two distinct odd prime numbers. Consider the following congruence equations:

$$x \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$
$$x \equiv 1 \pmod{q}$$

It is obvious that $x \equiv 1 \pmod{pq}$. But I am trying to prove it in a certain way, and I cannot find the appropriate argument.

Let $p^{-1}$ and $q^{-1}$ denote the inverse of $p$ and $q$ in $\pmod q$ and $\pmod p$ respectively.
Then
$$x \equiv p \cdot p^{-1} + q \cdot q^{-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{pq}$$

I am trying to directly show that $p \cdot p^{-1} + q \cdot q^{-1} \equiv 1 \pmod {pq}$.

To be more explicit we know $qq^{-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p \Rightarrow qq^{-1} = pk + 1 \Rightarrow q^{-1} = \frac{pk+1}{q}$ and similarly $pp^{-1} = qk'+1 \Rightarrow p^{-1} =\frac{qk'+1}{q}$

so it follows that

$$x \equiv p \frac{qk'+1}{p} + q \frac{pk+1}{q} = qk' + 1 + pk + 1 = qk' + pk + 2 \pmod {pq}$$

I do not know how to transform this expression to conclude that $qk' + pk + 2 \equiv 1 \pmod {pq}$

Comment: Your defns of $p^{-1}, q^{-1}$ have $\mod q$ twice.

Comment: Be careful with the accepted answer - in partcular it implicitly shifts betrween congruences mod $p$ & $q$ to congruences mod $pq$ without any explicit justification. I explicitly explain how to do that in my answer - since this is often troubling to students. If this were a homework problem you would be expected to rigorously justfiy that. Ditto for implicit use of uniqueness of inverses.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks for pointing it out. The reason that I accepted it is that it is the only answer that specifically addressed my question given the specific proof I was looking for. It dealt with collecting those $1$'s in $qk' + 1 + pk + 1$. Otherwise, I really liked your answer too.

Comment: I further expanded my answer to elaborate on various points. If anything remains unclear the let me know so I can elaborate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if you already know the [uniqueness criterion for CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242) then the sought result is *immediate*, i.e. both $\,\color{#0a0}{x_0 = 1}\,$ and the CRT formula $\,x_1 = p(p^{-1}\!\bmod q) + q(q^{-1}\!\bmod p)$ are clearly solutions of the system $\,x\equiv 1\pmod{\!p},\ x\equiv 1\pmod{\!q},\,$ so by $\rm\color{#c00}{ 
 U =}$ uniqueness $\,x_1\overset{\rm\color{#c00}U}\equiv \color{#0a0}{x_0\equiv 1}\pmod{\!pq}$.

Your question essentially asks for a (direct) proof of the uniqueness criterion. It is easy to show that the uniqueness criteria for [C]CRT,  linear diophantine equations, and modular inverses are all *equivalent* (to Euclid's lemma and [many other](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3057093/242) closely related basic results). Below is a direct proof via **inverse uniqueness** (with a [trivial one-line proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2033470/242)) & $\rm\color{#0a0}{Bezout\ identity}$ for $\gcd(p,q)=1$.

There are  $\,p',q'\in\Bbb Z\,$ with $\,\color{#0a0}{pp'\!+\!qq' = 1},\,$  so $\, \color{0a0}{pp'\equiv 1}\pmod{\!\color{darkorange1}q},\,$ so by **inverse uniqueness**  $\,p^{-1}\equiv p'\!\pmod{\!q},\,$ so $\, p^{-1^{\phantom{|^|}}}\!\!\! = p'\!+\!iq,\,$ some $\,i\in\Bbb Z.\,$ Similarly $\,q^{-1^{\phantom{|^|}}}\!\!\! = q'\!+\!jp,\,$ some $\,j\in \Bbb Z,\,$ therefore
$\, \color{#90f}{pp^{-1}\!+qq^{-1^{\phantom{|^|}}}}\!\!\! = p(p'\!+\!iq)+q(q'\!+\!jp)$ $ = pp'\!+\!qq'^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!\!+\color{#c00}{pq}(i\!+\!j)\:\!\equiv_{\color{#c00}{pq}}\:\!\color{#0a0}{pp'\!+\!qq'\, [= 1]}$

**Remark** $ $ No  answer actually "deals with the $\color{#0af}{1\!+\!1}$" -- which arise from your change from working with inverses $p^{-1},q^{-1}$ to working with their $\color{#c00}{{\rm negatives}\  \,k,k'}\,$ (which has the following effect on the Bezout identity summands: $\,i+j = 1\iff \color{#c00}{-i}+(\color{#c00}{-j})+\color{#0af}{2}=1).\,$ Rather, we *eliminate* the more unwieldly negative inverses by changing back to $\,p^{-1},q^{-1},\,$ i.e. read your last displayed equations in reverse
to get $\,\color{#c00}kp+\color{#c00}{k'}q+\color{#0af}2 = \color{#90f}{p^{-1}p+q^{-1}p},\,$ which is $\color{#0a0}{\equiv 1\pmod{pq}}\,$ as proved above.

As usual, these matters are clarified arithmetically when viewed via the (product) *ring* form of CRT (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3095229/242) for a simple intro requiring no knowledge of ring theory). Namely, your change to use of $\rm\color{#c00}{negated}$ inverses $\,\color{#c00}{k\equiv_q -p^{-1}}\,$ and $\,\color{#c00}{k'\equiv_p -q^{-1}}\,$ corresponds to a basis change to the negated standard basis $\,(0,\color{#c00}{-1}),(\color{#c00}{-1},0)\,$ vs. the normal standard basis $\,(0,1),(1,0).\,$ Then your final equation arises by negating the Bezout equation $\rm E$ then adding $\,\color{#0af}2,\,$ i.e. $\,\rm E\to -E\to \color{#0af}2+E,\,$ i.e.

$$\begin{align} 
 \ \overbrace{(0,1)\ +\ (1,0)\  \equiv \ (1,1)}^{\textstyle\!\! \color{#90f}{p^{-1}p\ +\,\ q^{-1}q}\ \equiv\ 1\ \ \ \ \ }
\!\overset{\rm -E}\iff \ \overbrace{(0,\color{#c00}{-1})+ (\color{#c00}{-1},0)\  \equiv \ (\color{#c00}{-1,-1})}^{\textstyle\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\color{#c00}{-p^{-1}}p\, \ \color{#c00}{-\ \ q^{-1}}q\, \ \ \equiv \ \ {-}1} \\[.7em]
\underset{\rm \color{#0af}2\,+\,E^{\phantom |}\!}\iff\ \ \underbrace{\color{#0af}{(2,2)}+ (0,\color{#c00}{-1})+(\color{#c00}{-1},0)\ \equiv\ (1,1)}_{\textstyle\!\!\! \color{#0af}{2}\ \ \ +\ \ \ \color{#c00}kp\ \ \ \ +\ \ \ \ \color{#c00}{k'}q\ \  \equiv\ \  1}\quad\ \ 
\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

Thus the three above congruences $\!\bmod{pq}\,$ are all trivially *equivalent*, so it suffices to prove any one of them. It is easiest to prove the first (as we did above) since it connects more immediately to the intuitive arithmetical notion of *inverses* and their *uniqueness*. As is often true in algebraic proofs, a slight algebraic transformation of equations may transform them into a form which better reveals innate arithmetical structure facilitating intuition and proof. As such we should strive to transform *towards* such  intuitive forms - not *away* from them (as do the above transforms to *negated* inverses and basis).

Comment: Or, directly, if congruence scaling is known: we can scale $\,p^{-1}\equiv p'\!\pmod{\!q}\,$ by $\,p\,$ to get $\,pp^{-1}\equiv pp'\pmod{\!pq}\,$ and similarly get $\,qq^{-1}\equiv qq'\pmod{\!pq},\,$ then add them. $\ \ $

Comment: **Beware** that it is a bit risky to denote $\,p^{-1}\bmod q\,$ by $\,p^{-1}$ (vs. $\,p^{-1}_{\:\!q}\,$ or other notation that makes *explicit* the dependence on the modulus $\,q)\,$ because it faciltates (common) errors that occur when ignoring the dependence on the modulus.

Answer (score 1):

So what you're missing is control over $k, k'$. These aren't just arbitrary numbers. How can we determine these values?

By Bezout, there exists integers such that $ pa + qb = 1$.
Then, $ p^{-1} \equiv a \pmod{q}$ and $ q^{-1} \equiv b \pmod{p}$.
Hence, $p p^{-1} + q q^{-1} \equiv pa + qb \equiv 1 \pmod{pq}$.

---

If we wanted to pursue your approach, then $a \equiv p^{-1} = \frac{qk'+1}{p}$, $b \equiv q^{-1} = \frac{pk+1}{q}$.
So $ qk'+1 + pk+1 \equiv pa + qb \equiv 1  \pmod{pq}$

Comment: The *implicit* shifting between congruences mod $p$ & $q$ to congruences mod $pq$ will likely lead to problems for many beginners. In particular if a student submitted a solution written as above they would surely lose credit for not justifying such. Ditto for implicit use of uniqueness of inverses (or equivalent uniqueness criteria).

Comment: True, I skipped a step of explaining that if $\gcd(m, n) = 1$, then $ a \equiv b \pmod{m} \Leftrightarrow an \equiv bn \pmod{mn}$.  While this is well-known, it is often done via the property that OP is trying to prove, which makes this argument circular.

Answer (score 0):

An isomorphism between $\Bbb Z_{pq}$ and $\Bbb Z_p×\Bbb Z_q$ can be defined by $$1\mapsto (1,1).$$

In general,  using Bezout,  we find $a,b$ such that $ap+bq=1$.  Then we do $$(x,y) \leftrightarrow yap+xbq.$$

The constant case of the Chinese remainder theorem (CCRT) falls out easily:
$$c\leftrightarrow (c,c).$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by showing it directly. There's an approach without the explicit concept of the modular inverse.

$x \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$

$x \equiv 1 \pmod{q}$

$x=kp+1$. $gcd(p,q)=1$

$kp+1\equiv 1 \pmod {q}$

$kp\equiv 0  \pmod{q}\implies q|k.$

$x=mpq+1\implies x\equiv 1 \pmod{pq}$

Comment: I understand there are alternatives. But I am trying to prove it in a specific way.