# Do we have that $x$ divides $cb$ with $x,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$ implies $\gcd(x,b)>1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to prove that the set of zero divisors of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/_{b\mathbb{Z}} $ is equal to $\{[x] \in \mathbb{Z}/_{b\mathbb{Z}}: \gcd(x,b)>1\}$. Therefore I started with the set of zero divisors equals: $\{[x] \in \mathbb{Z}/_{b\mathbb{Z}}: cx = db \, \space \text{for some} \space  c,d \in \mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}\}$. And now to my question: Do we have:
$x$ divides $db \implies \gcd(x,b)>1$.

If this holds (why/why not?), I would be done.

Comment: Perhaps, if $x > 1$; since $x \mid db$ either $x\mid b$ or $x\mid d$ by Euclid's lemma, and so you may take $x\mid b$ and thus $\gcd(x,b) = x$.

Comment: @Spectre How can i just take $x$ divides $b$, and ignore the case that $x$ could divide $d$ instead of b?

Comment: did you mean, $x \mid d$ in your comment?

Comment: Yes, I will correct it

Comment: I only meant that you _can_ take it like that.

Comment: the 3 possibilities when $x \mid db$  are : a) $x \mid d$ , b) $x \mid b$ or c) $pf(x) \in (pf(b) \cup pf(d))$ (I used my own notation $pf(x)$ to represent the set of prime factors of $x$).

Comment: That confuses me, though, so I can't give you an exact answer and so I'd say 'Wait till Euclid comes on your way'

Comment: By definition, $x$ is a zero-divisor $\!\bmod b$ if  $\,x\not\equiv 0\,$ and for some $\,c\not\equiv 0\,$ we have $\,cx\equiv 0,\, $ i.e. iff  $\,b\mid cx,\, b\nmid c,x\,$ But if $\,(b,x)=1\,$ then by [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252748/242) $\,b\mid cx\Rightarrow b\mid c,\,$ contra hypothesis. Thus $(b,x)\neq 1,\,$ so $(b,x)>1.\,$ See the linked dupe for other proofs.