# Coincident products and coprime factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I have huge problems to understand the following (simple?) theorem:

Let $a,b,c,d$ naturals such that $a\cdot b = c\cdot d$ and $\operatorname{gcd}(b,d) = 1$. Then it follows that $$ b\mid c \text{ and } d\mid a.$$

I just don't get a proof for it. Can anyone provide me maybe a cause for thought? I really don't know how to start.

Comment: Each integer can be written in an unique way as a product of prime factors. Write $a.b$
 in such product of prime factors.

Comment: So let $a = \prod\limits p^{\alpha_p}, b = \prod\limits q^{\beta_q}, c = \prod\limits r^{\gamma_r}, d = \prod\limits s^{\delta_s}$. I know that there is no common prime factors in $b$ and $d$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the theorem that
$$
(b, d)=1 \Rightarrow \exists m, n \in \mathbb{Z} \text { s.t. } m b+n d=1 \tag*{(*)} 
$$
Multiplying $(*)$ by $c$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
& m b c+n c d=c \\
\Rightarrow \quad  & m b c+n a b=c \\
\Rightarrow \quad  & b(m c+n a)=c \\
\Rightarrow \quad & b \mid c 
\end{aligned}
$$
Multipling $(*)$ by $a$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
& m a b+n a d=a \\
\Rightarrow \quad  & m c d+n a d=a \\
\Rightarrow \quad & d(m c+n a)=a \\
\Rightarrow \quad & d \mid a 
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: It’s my pleasure to help.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs (& PSQs), cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @mathquester One shouldn't (*twice*) repeat the well-known proof of [Euclid's Lemma (by Bezout)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252748/242), as above. Rather one should invoke it *by name*.